# Find a space in UTF-8 strings, do I need mb_strpos?

Tags: php, multibyte

I have a string in UTF-8.

```
$string = "ãçé êíõ";
```

I need to find the position of the space.
I have to use `mb_strpos($string,' ');` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to find the *character* position of the space, then yes. `strpos` will not do because the byte value `0x20` (UTF-8 code point for space) can also be encountered as part of a code point [encoded over multiple bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description).

Also, do not forget to specify the encoding -- either explicitly on the `mb_strpos` call or by setting a default with [`mb_internal_encoding`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php).

Comment: Did a test and strpos returns 6 :), so yes I need mb_strpos

Answer (score 2):

Note that just using `mb_strpos` may not be sufficient - there are several code points that display as a space. See e.g. [this list](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm) - the second most common space character (second to the default ASCII space `U+0020`, decimal `32`) is the nonbreakable space (`U+00A0`); you may need to check for that one, too - or replace it into the "usual" space character.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636559/strange-utf8-string-comparison