# fopen() and passing unicode file name

Tags: php, windows, utf-8, filesystems, fopen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UTF8 Filenames in PHP and Different Unicode Encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089966/utf8-filenames-in-php-and-different-unicode-encodings)
>   [What encoding are filenames in NTFS stored as?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050973/what-encoding-are-filenames-in-ntfs-stored-as)

I must to create file.

File name has unicode chars, e.g:

```
K. Wiśniewska-Bugaj
```

I try to echo file name, it's ok. But in file system it's:

```
K. WiĹ›niewska-Bugaj
```

I can't change file names unfortunately.

Comment: Which file-system are you using? It does not look like it supports UTF-8 at all.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Where was Windows mentioned?

Comment: Linux [can support unicode](http://hektor.umcs.lublin.pl/~mikosmul/computing/articles/linux-unicode.html) and by the looks of the name, that link should be right up your alley.

Comment: @DaveRandom: It wasn't. But if it was *nix, it would have worked.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Not if the file-system uses some other encoding than UTF-8. I think that depends on the locale a bit.

Comment: @hakra: That would put the system some time in the 90s.

Comment: Depends on the sysadmins taste I'd say. But right, you normally should use UTF-8 there, especially for us web-kiddies.

Comment: @keram What version of PHP are you using, what code are you executing, more info required.

Comment: @Toby Allen. I am using PHP 5.3.12. I changed the code, now I am changing filenames to ASCII. Question is for deleting.